# windows 7 maven 2 install

Tags: maven-2, environment-variables

I'm about to work through a book, "Flex on Java" and it's asked me to install maven 2+ i downloaded maven from the apache site. 
Added :

```
M2_HOME = C:\apache-maven-2.2.1
```

and

```
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
```

to the environment vars according to the instructions at http://maven.apache.org/download.html
then it gets to number 6 which says 
"In the same dialog, update/create the Path environment variable in the user variables and prepend the value `%M2%` to add Maven available in the command line."

Which environment variable should i edit and add `%M2%` to?

After googling i found a post which says "append", not prepend to the value of `JAVA_HOME`
I've tried prepending and appending it to the java home var but when i try to do 
an mvn command from the command line it says its not recognised.

Never used maven before so this is my first set up. Can anyone see what i'm not doing right or what else i need to do to be able to use the mvn command, please and thank you.

Comment: as Dave mentioned above, also add M2 as a system variable (probably in a windows 7 thing)

Comment: prepend or append should never be a problem. but pay attention to use of `;`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The environment variable you should edit is `path`.

The route on Windows 7 is:

*Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables ->* The `path` variable is right on the *system variable*s area

The `path` variable specifies a group of directories and/or paths that Windows searches for commands definitions. You should append to the end of this variable value the value `;%M2%` (**note** the semi-colon, different paths should be separated by them) in order for Windows to be able to find the Maven command definitions.

Appending `;%M2` at the end of the path environment variables is the same as appending `;C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin`

To test that everything is ok, type `mvn --version`, if everything is right then the current Maven version you're using should be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh, thank you.
I was focusing on the user env. vars and kept misreading that so i didn't realise it meant the system path var. 

thanks again.

Comment: Sorry , i did the same but I still can not mvn -v , but if I enther the bin dir , it works. Why? Please help!

Answer (score 11):

for further information and future googlers : 
i just tried to run maven , so i added the M2_HOME to "user variables" but the system failed to recognize mvn --version command, so i added M2_HOME to System Variables and it solved the problem (the apache told us to add the M2_HOME in user variables)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue.
As mentioned Dave and Nic M2_HOME and M2 should be added to the System variables.

Answer (score 1):

It is strange because JAVA_HOME is perfectly picked as a USER variable whereas on Windows7 mvn is not properly installed unless its variables (both %M2% and %M2_HOME%) are set as SYSTEM variables.  I can't explain the rationale behind it but its a workaround.
[windows7](/questions/tagged/windows7)[maven3](/questions/tagged/maven3)

Comment: Actually JAVA_HOME is not picked up. What is really happening is that java executables are also located inside C:\Windows\System32 which is added to the system level Path variable. If you want to run custom java you have to specify its directory location before System32 in System level Path variable. If you create User level Path variable its values are appended to System level Path variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issues when installing Maven. But you do not have to add any System variables. Follow the instructions and add all necessary User variables, including a new "Path" variable.

Ignore that it does not look to be working and run mvn --version from cmd and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following the above advice and I still had issues getting the mvn --version to run.  I searched on line and I found a similar site that gave the following advice.

"Please run the command SET in a command window and paste the relevant
 parts here, i.e. M2_HOME, M2, JAVA_HOME and PATH."

The instructions on the Apache site weren't very clear so I will reattempt to make is obvious, even to the most casual of observers.

1) Go to the advanced settings.  The shortcut is the windows + pause.

2) In Win7, click on Advanced System Settings.  This will open up a System Properties Box

3) On the advanced tab, click on Environment Variables.

4) Under the Environment Variables there are two areas: User Variables and System Variables.  When you click on edit, they both have the same box.  As discussed here and on the site, we need enter paths and variable names so Windows will automatically check your Java / Maven area when you enter in Maven commands.  Since I had trouble I put the Java variables (JAVA_HOME), the Maven Variables (M2 and M2_HOME), the paths (these are unique to your machine) in both User Variables and in System Variables.

5) If this still does not work, you have to open a command line and type the following:
"SET M2_HOME".  After typing 'SET M2_HOME' you should see some activity.  If you don't, you have made a typing mistake or you are not typing in the correct paths. If you see activity, type SET M2.  Then follow up by typing SET JAVA_HOME and  SET PATH.

If you see activity after typing each of the SET commands you should be able to get the 'mvn --version' command to work.

This worked for me.  I hope it works for you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Some people forget that if you already have a command line window open whilst your setting the Env Vars then there is a good chance you will continue to view errors.

Once you have set the vars, try opening a new command line window ;)

Answer (score 0):

When entering PATH variable "prepending" means to put it before Java path so it will look like this:

```
%M2%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Download Maven.
Extract it in your directory say :C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5
Set its path: go to => Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables -> The path variable is right on the *system variable*s area
Click 'New'
Variable name: M2_HOME
VAriable value: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5
Click 'ok'

Append '%M2_HOME%\bin;' to path variable.

Restart your system, CMD=> mvn -v
```