# Maven: mvn command not found

Tags: windows, maven

I set the following system veriables (OS = Vista):

```
M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\Maven 
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin 
path = %M2%
```

If i run mvn -- version I get:

```
mvn: command not found
```

Anyone have any idea why this could be? 
Thanks.

Comment: You can check this answer to the same question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402214/windows-7-maven-2-install

Comment: Do you have the problem described [here](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-account-administration/7649-setting-environment-variables.html) related to permissions and rights?

Comment: If you make any changes to your system variables, make sure you close and open a new instance of your cmd line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on windows, what i suppose you need to do set the PATH like this:

```
SET PATH=%M2%
```

furthermore i assume you need to set your path to something like C:...\apache-maven-3.0.3\ cause this is the default folder for the windows archive.
On the other i assume you need to add the path of maven to your and not set it to only maven so you setting should look like this:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%M2%
```

Comment: I added %M2_HOME% to my current path yes.
And I extracted maven into c:\program files\maven. 

Is it possible that he doesn't know M2_HOME ? Although it shows up in the list of System Variables.

Comment: Sorry i was using M2_HOME instead of M2

Comment: I have made the answer based on your expressions which uses M2 and M2_HOME. You could short cut that by putting C:\..\Maven\bin into your PATH directly.

Comment: First expression seems wrong as it would replace the path by %M2%. Would also recommend to update the answer based on the comments as misleading if not reading the comments

Answer (score 21):

Maven setup:

a. install maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

b. unzip maven and keep in C drive.

c. Set **MAVEN_HOME** in system variable. 
[image]

d. **Set path for maven**
[image]

Answer (score 11):

I followed this tutorial: [How to install Maven on Windows](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)

But running `mvn -version`, I still got:

> mvn: command not found

So, I closed the current git window, and opened a new one.
Everything went okay :)

Comment: git window does not hot-reload the environment variable : so if you modify PATH, you have to close and reopen the git bash.

Answer (score 5):

I tried solutions from other threads. Adding M2 and M2_HOME at System variables, and even at User variables. Running cmd as admin. None of the methods worked.

But today I added entire path to maven bin to my System variables "PATH" (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin) besides other paths, and so far it's working good. Hopefully it'll stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tutorial passed by @emdhie will help a lot.
[How install maven](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm)

But, i followed and still getting `mvn: command not found`

I found this solution to know what was wrong in my configuration:

I opened the command line and called this command:

```
../apache-maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn --version
```

After that i got the correct JAVA_HOME and saw that my JAVA_HOME was wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run '*path*' in command prompt and ensure that the maven installation directory is listed.
2. Ensure the maven is installed in 'C:\Program Files\Maven'.

Comment: Maven is installed there, and path is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the spaces. I had my variable at the System variables but it didn't work. When I changed variable `Progra~1 = 'Program Files'` everything works fine.

```
M2_HOME C:\Progra~1\Maven\apache-maven-3.1.1
```

I also moved my `M2_HOME` at the end of the `PATH(%M2_HOME%\bin)` I'm not sure if this has any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps [MAVEN](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)

Again this does not work, hit this command in the Powershell

```
$env:Path = "$env:Path;C:\path\to\maven\bin"
```

Make sure to close and reopen the powershell and try `mvn -version`

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install maven - this made it for me on a vagrant machine with docker installed

Answer (score -1):

mvn -version

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: mvn is not available in the first place so this wont work