# Maven clean install: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I don´t know what´s the problem. Trying to install maven for a college project. I already installed maven as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649707/maven-mvn-command-not-found). [Picture Environmental Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARiCg.png), [maven version in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiIoG.png)  And I also tried to delete the .m2 file. When I try to install maven over the plugin in InteliJ, I get the message: "process terminated" with no extra info. Then I tried to install over the terminal with mvn clean install and i got this.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.college:sprinttool:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 50, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 55, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.college:sprinttool >--------------------
[INFO] Building sprinttool 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ sprinttool ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\Code Practices\sprinttool\sprinttool\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ sprinttool ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.740 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-26T22:56:19+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project sprinttool: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Then I ran "mvn clean install -X" for more Information and it gives out this in addition.

```
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException (CoderResult.java:274)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead (StreamDecoder.java:352)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read (StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read (InputStreamReader.java:181)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1 (BufferedReader.java:210)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read (BufferedReader.java:287)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill (BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read (BufferedReader.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.BoundedReader.read (BoundedReader.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read (MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read (MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:197)
    at java.io.Reader.read (Reader.java:229)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy (IOUtil.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy (IOUtil.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile (FileUtils.java:1908)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I honestly have no clue what it is telling me. Is it because there is something wrong with my pom.xml? Pls help me! Thank you in advance.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.college</groupId>
    <artifactId>sprinttool</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sprintplanningtool</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Edit: I used the spring boot intitializer to create the project.

Comment: You are filtering items which should not being filtered. Changing the version of the plugin does not help it only covers the issue. Furthermore the exclusion for JUnit Vintage engine is not necessary anymore since Spring Boot 2.4.0. Remove also the versions for things which are handled by Spring Boot... and remove plugin dependencies and remove source/target configuration because you have use `<jave.version>..` ...

Comment: The solution of @khmarbaise doesn't work for me. Still the same problem. After some research I found this Issue at the Jira of Maven. I'll go down to Version 3.1.0 until they fixed it. https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MRESOURCES/issues/MRESOURCES-273?filter=allopenissues To wich I came through this issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24346

Comment: see also: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MRESOURCES/issues/MRESOURCES-273?filter=allopenissues

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm facing the same issue in my project and *only* text files are filtered. The project doesn't use Spring neither.

Comment: Since maven-resources-plugin 3.2.0, setting the value of `propertiesEncoding` can fix the problem for properties files filtered. See : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It might be a new bug coming with some latest release of *Spring-boot* (and then : *Spring*).

I had it. The workaround is to put in your `pom.xml` this corrected dependency :

```xml
<!-- Pour contourner un bug à la génération par Spring-boot 2.4.x : 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project application-etude: Input length = 1 -->               
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

But this is a temporary workaround to 'save you' at the time the trouble fall upon you.

The way to correct the trouble correctly is to ensure that your `properties` files are now correctly encoded in UTF-8.

Because the underlying cause that makes this problem appearing is the presence of "junk chars" replacing accented characters when ISO-8859-1 (or other) properties files are considered as UTF-8 ones by *Spring*, while they aren't.

Comment: The problem is that items being filtered which should not being filter. The downgrade only covers the real problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise The real problem that __every user__ of that new _Spring_ or _Spring-boot_ version encounter... So let _Spring_ team correcting it and until that, this workaround is working well, ok?

Comment: No that work-a-round covers a problem with filtering...That means someone is filtering things which should **not** being filtered which can cause real issue. So this does not help... and No it's not the responsibility of the Spring team..it's the responsibility of the user...

Comment: @khmarbaise And how do you explain that every user encounter this problem now with the new _Spring_ version? Are all of them doing wrong? Me, the poster, the one from the web site where I've learned once the solution? And what is the good solution ? Take time to write your answer please. We will judge it too...

Comment: @khmarbaise Don't wait to write your answer, please. I will remove mine as soon as you can offer another solution that is plenty working. Regards.

Comment: See @khmarbaise answer below it addresses the root cause of the problem. To see the files that are not correctly handled by the resource plugin use the `-X -e` flags when building the project.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this issue has nothing to do with spring-boot but the maven-resources-plugin version 3.2.0. Reverting to 3.1.0 solved a build issue. Note: in a build that does not use spring-boot

Comment: The -X -e works to find out the problematic file. It would be fine if the plugin itself stated the right error, instead of Input length = 1

Comment: You're right, the problem comes from a `.properties` file that contains malformed characters when read in UTF-8. Fixing this file solves the problem.

Answer (score 56):

The root cause of the exception is that some resources contain resources which should not filtered (aka binary). The correct solution is to define an exclude for file extensions which should not filtered [like the following](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
          </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Well, if I go with your solution. The Project would not build like before?

Comment: And what does that mean: `The Project would not build like before`?

Comment: It means, It did build after I used the solution of Marc Le Bihan. But now it doesn´t.

Comment: @khmarbaise But what resources are you talking about that should be filtered ? The opener of the post have none to filter.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer.  To find out which files are causing the exception you should run your build with `-X -e` flags i.e `mvn clean package -X -e -P some_profile`

Comment: For me it was not clear until deep digging into the problem. It is good to say, that it is not working because there are characters in files which are not UTF-8 encoded or whatever sourceEncoding is set. Resource plugin 3.2 is strict about that, but versions 3.1 and bellow are benevolent. So answer is clear, what to do but does not state exactly what is the problem and motivation to not downgrade to 3.1 version. Problem applies also to non binary files.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding in the pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Here is the comment that help me solved the problem :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24346#issuecomment-740345146

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: While downgrading the plugin version as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910205/336888) did work for me, it seems as though the newer versions of maven-resource-plugin require a matching sourceEncoding.  So, this answer feels more future proof to me when using version 3.2.0+

Comment: I already had this too and it didn't work; you could have binary files in your `resources` folder that could cause this issue and this solution wouldn't work. It only worked in your case because it was in the code

Answer (score 23):

In my case, the error happened because I had properties files encoded with ANSI, while maven was trying to use UTF-8. I fixed it by converting my properties files to UTF-8, and then running `mvn clean compile`.

Comment: Thank, In Eclipse I go to Terminal, CD <folder> then mvn clean compile, then Refresh my project and it works

Answer (score 22):

In my case, the error was due to accents on "application.properties"

It would certainly be far easier to fix such errors if the tool simply gave a message saying that a certain file contains invalid characters...

For the record, the relevant log part, after running `mvn clean package -e -X`, was this one:

```
[DEBUG] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resource 'application.properties'.
[DEBUG] filtering D:\Java\PreVendaAPI\src\main\resources\application.properties to D:\Java\PreVendaAPI\target\classes\application.properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's what did it for me, doesn't help that the error itself has no mention of the conversion error, thank you for the fix!

Comment: Your log snippet hinted me to the error causing file.

Answer (score 19):

The problem is with the maven-resources-plugin. Newer versions of this plugin are less lenient than the older versions. Unfortunately, the error message that is displayed when the Maven build fails (Input length = 1) is only helpful if you recognize it from previous experience with character set problems in Java.

You can add some options to the Maven build command so it will display DEBUG level output and a full stacktrace on build failures. Try this as your first step in diagnosing the root cause:

```
mvn -e -X clean test
```

It will output a LOT of info to the console during the build with these options turned on. Just wait until the failure happens and check the end of the console output. You should see a full stacktrace at the end that will make more sense. Just before the stacktrace, you should also see the name of the file in your project that caused the error. For me, I saw output like this:

```
directory C:\GITROOT\conndev\repos\conn-lamp-server\src\test\resources
excludes []
includes []
[DEBUG] ignoreDelta true
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[DEBUG] Copying file application-inttest.properties
[DEBUG] file application-inttest.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resource 'application-inttest.properties'.
[DEBUG] filtering C:\GITROOT\conndev\repos\conn-lamp-server\src\test\resources\application-inttest.properties to C:\GITROOT\conndev\repos\conn-lamp-server\target\test-classes\application-inttest.properties
[DEBUG] Copying file DummyExcelFile.xls
[DEBUG] file DummyExcelFile.xls has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resource 'DummyExcelFile.xls'.
[DEBUG] filtering C:\GITROOT\conndev\repos\conn-lamp-server\src\test\resources\DummyExcelFile.xls to C:\GITROOT\conndev\repos\conn-lamp-server\target\test-classes\DummyExcelFile.xls
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  37.927 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-26T10:11:09-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I know that a file in my test resources directory was the problem:

```
src\test\resources\DummyExcelFile.xls
```

Older versions of the resources plugin must have been quietly suppressing the problem. I won't include the full stacktrace here, but this is the important line from the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I've seen this before. It happens when a text file cannot be read by a Java 'reader' class because the file contains one or more characters that are invalid for the character set used by the reader. In my case, it was trying to read a binary file as text, so that was never going to work! The same problem could happen if you have a text file that contains unusual characters (such as those from European languages with accents) and those characters are not valid for the character set you are using (such as UTF-8). All these problems can be solved with some POM configuration.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <propertiesEncoding>UTF-8</propertiesEncoding>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>zip</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If you are using a different character set from UTF-8, just substitute yours in the XML snippet above. Do the same for any file extensions that you want the maven-resource-plugin to ignore when it does filtering.

Note that I have intentionally omitted the `<version>` for the maven-resources-plugin block above. This is because I am using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` in my POM and the version of many dependencies is inherited from the parent. If you do not use a parent, then you will have to explicitly set the version you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. After removing german umlauts ('ü') from comments in my propertie files, they should be filtered, the problem is gone!

Answer (score 4):

By default, maven-resources-plugin uses `project.build.sourceEncoding` when filtering resources (which defaults to `UTF-8`).

The java standard for `.properties` files requires `ISO-8859-1` encoding.

To resolve this, you can explicitely configure how `.properties` Files should be filtered:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <propertiesEncoding>ISO-8859-1</propertiesEncoding>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is also described in the official documentation of the plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, and fixed it using the below changes in my pom.xml build plugin.

```
<project>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me.
I also had to add maven-compiler-plugin and maven-war-plugin with the same version.

Answer (score 3):

You need exclude binary resourses.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertiesEncoding>UTF-8</propertiesEncoding>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>xlsx</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of your resources contains a character not in the ISO-8859-1 codepage, and this can cause disturbance here:

```
   at java.io.Reader.read (Reader.java:229)
   at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy (IOUtil.java:199)
```

A typical error might be an accentuated character in a .properties file.

Answer (score 1):

This message came up today, here is what I did to resolve it:

I used mvn to analyze the resources like this:

```
mvn -X process-test-resources
```

This way mvn returned the name of the file wich was causing the error:

```
[DEBUG] filtering .../messages.properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  x
[INFO] Finished at: y
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on foo: Input length = 1 ->
```

Turned out messages.properties contained special chars which had not been escaped properly. So I escaped them in the i18n-file and after that I was able to build again.

Answer (score 1):

I Belive that error heppens because have some problems of compatibility
R: The possible solution is to insert this plugin in `pom.xml`

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find the problem using the `clean install -e -X` goals on my run configuration in eclipse (you can also run it on command line).

---

In my case was a problem with angular classes generated with a script to auto build a .war with an angular project. In some point of the script it was failing and it made the command to delete the public folder built in the resources folder of my project doesn't execute (`del /Q src\main\resources\public\*.*`), so the files keep in my project making a headache the next time I tried to compile in my IDE.
The solution was deleting from the IDE this folder and it worked on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error but none of the solutions here worked because:

- I already had the `sourceEncoding` set to `UTF-8` in my `pom.xml`
- I don't want to downgrade a plugin for the sake of some "bug"
- My problem comes from a binary file, not just some special characters in a properties file

Both OP and my errors are due to a file not being copied correctly from the resources folder. Re-running the build with `-X` or `-e` shows in the stack trace that the offending file (in my case) was my `.der` cert file in my `resources` folder which makes sense.

So the fix was simply to add to my `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <build>
        ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.der</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
    </build>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are defining *application.property* and *application.yml* at the same time. If you want to use both of them, please try plug the *maven-resources-plugin*

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error when writing non utf-8 characters in a comment in application.properties file. I deleted those characters and it's working !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This error occured when I put this comment in `application.properties` file:

```
0.075 = ± 7,5%
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8 </project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Use this in pom.xml file that will definetly work.

*Caution this syntax only works from java version 13 and later Use the previous syntax, if you are using older java versions

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I doubt you put this syntax in a .properties file. Can you doublecheck, please?

Comment: @R.A you're right, this is most likely the `<properties>` element in pom.xml

Answer (score -2):

Using this dependency solved this problem of mine

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

For me stopping the server helped

```
(On Windows 10) npx kill-port your_port
```