# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources fails with MalformedInputException

Tags: java, maven

We had been having problems trying to run a mvn -X -e clean package on our project workspace and it was producing this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project eWell-web: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources **(default-resources)** on project eWell-web: Input length = 1
```

I highlighted the important part as that helped us isolate the issue.  Evidently, from reading other articles, we determined that there was some extraneous character in a file in the default-resources path. In our case, this is src/main/resouces.

The bad file had a message that ended with:

location restrictions in ï¿½ 3215.

those characters are 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD

This displayed in the text editor as: location restrictions in � 3215.

How were we supposed to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We opened up each of the files in NotePad++ which has an encoding menu option and examined them.  One of the files, called messages.properties, was not UTF-8 encoded.  We converted it to UTF-8 and then ran a compare against the two files.

In terms of display, this now displays as a paragraph marker: location restrictions in § 3215.

which is 0xC2, 0xA7

And the maven command ran fine again.

This is similar to the thread here:
[Maven Clean Install Failed to Execute Goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910112/maven-clean-install-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resou), and there are a lot of answers there that simply put us on a wild goose chase.  The two most useful answers were:

[Invalid characters can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69575799/1955401).
[Wrong encoding in properties files vs Maven (ANSI vs UTF-8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68923894/1955401)