# failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 when building java application with maven 3.9.0

Tags: java, maven

The java application is building perfectly fine with maven 3.6.0-3.8.x . However with maven 3.9.0 it is giving this strange error for html or xml files.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) on project {project_name}: filtering {path1}/30168019.html to {path2}/30168019.html failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]

First I thought might be some encoding issue wrt maven but in the pom file it is mentioned utf-8 itself. Does anyobody have any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: Get maven to give you the stacktraces for the errors; e.g. `mvn -e ...`.  The problem >is< most likely something to do with encoding.  Maybe some of the HTML files it is copying are NOT properly encoded UTF-8.  Maybe Maven is trying to read them as UTF-8 and that is failing.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and fixed it by adding the below plugin to my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

This is a workaround, and the proper fix is to make sure your files are properly encoded. More details in the selected answer here: [Maven clean install: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910112/maven-clean-install-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resou)

Answer (score 2):

The first response helped me, but it still resulted in a 'Warning'. I resolved it by making the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```