# Broadleaf commerce Adding maven home in build.properties file

Tags: maven, path, m2eclipse, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to run the *[Broadleaf Demosite project](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite)* in eclipse. I have setup the Demosite by following the instructions from the 
[Getting started](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/current/Getting-Started.html) guide from broadleaf site. The default code in the `build.properties` file inside the `Demosite` maven parent project shows this,

```
#required
maven.home=/usr/share/maven

#optional
jrebel.path=/usr/lib/jrebel/jrebel.jar
```

As maven.home is required to start up the server and so now that I have downloaded and extracted the `maven 3.0.4` in `C:\Users\admin\Downloads\apache-maven-3.0.4\lib`.

What is the path I have to specify in the `maven.home` line in the properties file,

Should it be something like this?

```
maven.home=C:\User\admin\apache-maven-3.0.4\lib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the `maven.home` to point to the path like this,

```
maven.home==/Users/admin/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4
```

[Download maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and extract it wherever you want in you computer. Set the path to that directory using command prompt,

```
C:\Users\admin>set PATH="c:\Users\admin\downloads\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin";%PATH%
```

Now I'm able to start the jetty server in eclipse with BUILD SUCCESS.

**UPDATE:**

As the above solution only works for once and you need to run that command every-time you restart the system. For it to work always you have to set the `PATH` environment variable for maven. Look at [How to install maven in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402214/windows-7-maven-2-install) for a permanent solution. Once installed run the following to check if you have installed maven correctly and to check other variables are properly set.

**CMD PROMPT**

```
C:\Users\admin>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 14:14:56+0530)
Maven home: c:\Users\admin\Downloads\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_32, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
C:\Users\admin>
```

If all the above works fine then in the properties file, you have to specify the maven home directory which in my case was,

```
C:/Users/admin/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4
```

Sometimes the single forward slash(`/`) doesn't work in Windows, so replace it with double-forward slash(`//`) and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is shipped into a .zip archive. So unzip maven where do you want. Let's say somewhere like :

`C:\User\admin\apache-maven-3.0.4\`

then set into your `build.properties`

`maven.home=C:/User/admin/apache-maven-3.0.4`

and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Default value in build.properties file:

```
#required
maven.home=/usr/share/maven
```

You have to follow the below format:-

```
#required
maven.home=C://Program Files//apache-maven-3.0.5-bin//apache-maven-3.0.5
```