# Maven 2.2.1 installed, but not configured

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-2

I'm having a problem with a maven environmnet, if I try to execute the command `mvn --version` I see maven installed, but in eclipse (Indigo) I can't execute maven commands.

I've downloaded the plugin `m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse` and restarted eclipse, but I got no changes.

Then, my question is: I have to uninstall all environment and re-install, or just configure something, or something else?

PS.: I'm using Windows7

Comment: In Eclipse you have Maven 3 and not Maven 2.2.1. Is there any special reason using an old Maven version?

Comment: some systems only uses old maven . so we need maven 2.2.1 .

Answer (score 0):

you need to add maven to your path variable

The route on Windows 7 is:

Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables -> The path variable is right on the *system variable*s area

The path variable specifies a group of directories and/or paths that Windows searches for commands definitions. You should append to the end of this variable value the value ;%M2% (note the semi-colon, different paths should be separated by them) in order for Windows to be able to find the Maven command definitions.

Appending ;%M2 at the end of the path environment variables is the same as appending ;C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin

To test that everything is ok, type mvn --version, if everything is right then the current Maven version you're using should be displayed on the screen.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402214/windows-7-maven-2-install)